# What are all the endpoints in the Microsoft Graph API that are relevant for SharePoint?

Tags: api, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-sdks

I would like to know what is the subset of endpoints in the Microsoft Graph API are relevant for accessing Sharepoint? The Microsoft Graph API has a significant number of endpoints for its various Microsoft applications. I am designing another API that will consume a subset of these endpoints that are relevant for accessing Sharepoint. To complete this, I would like to know what endpoints within the Microsoft Graph API are relevant for this application?

A google search provides me with some endpoints which are associated with Sharepoint. I am looking for a comprehensive list.
https://www.concurrency.com/blog/november-2018/using-the-graph-api-with-sharepoint

I would like some help and guidance on obtaining this list. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Official Microsoft Graph docs on should help with this research:

- [SharePoint sites and content API overview](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/sharepoint-concept-overview)
- I'd also check the [Graph explorer](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/graph-explorer#) SharePoint samples (Be sure to click the show more samples link)
  [image]
- [Working with SharePoint sites in Microsoft Graph](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/sharepoint?view=graph-rest-1.0)

This table in that list link might be especially helpful: [image]